# Umbraco get llist of pages created by user

Tags: c#, .net, content-management-system, umbraco

Is possible to get pages which were created by user in umbraco cms. For example my username is admin, and I want to get list all of pages which were created by me using c# code (page name and page url).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible and pretty straight forward. Here are a couple of examples (I'm using razor to spit out the values, but this could easily be put into a user control, or written out to a file or whatever):

Using [DynamicNode](http://our.umbraco.org/documentation/reference/querying/DynamicNode/):

```
@{
    var userId = 0; //admin
    var root = Library.NodeById(-1);
    var nodes = root.Descendants().Where("CreatorId == @0", userId);

    foreach (var node in nodes)
    {
        @:@node.Id, @node.Name, @node.Url<br />
    }
}
```

Using NodeFactory and [uQuery](http://our.umbraco.org/documentation/Reference/Querying/uQuery/):

```
@{
    var userId = 0; //admin
    var root = new Node(-1);
    var nodes = root.GetDescendantNodes(n => n.CreatorID == userId);

    foreach (var node in nodes)
    {
        @:@node.Id, @node.Name, @node.Url<br />
    }
}
```

Just replace `0` withe the Id of your user.